# Printing Twitter Bootstrap correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I'm really struggeling to print my Twitter Bootstrap views correctly, and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. I've added a custom "print.css" which overrides some of the original bootstrap styling, as well of styling some of my own components.

This is my print dialog:
[image]

Not sure if you can tell so easily from the image, but the well has lost its background as well as not spanning across the entire page width. Also, the 'columns' or 'spans' seem to be all wonky. Page is built up like this: (Only showing first row to keep it clean)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div style="height: 150px; width: 300px">
                    <img class="img-rounded" src='data:image/png;base64,@Model.Unit.Image64' />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                ...
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            ...Pie chart control
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
            ...Bar chart control
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my print.css:

```
@media print {
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 1.4em;
        word-spacing: 1px;
        letter-spacing: 0.2px;
        font: 13px Arial, Helvetica,"Lucida Grande", serif;
        color: #000;
    }

    #print-btn #update-btn #nav-left #nav-bar, #selectUnitContainer, .navbar, .sidebar-nav {
        display: none;
    }

    #print-btn, #update-btn, #units {
        display: none;
    }

    #nav-left {
        display: none;
    }

    #report-container {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .well .span12{
        width: 100%;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .navbar {
        display: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to find a decent solution for this? Would be interesting to know, as I myself program a few sites with Bootstrap! =)

Comment: Hi @MackieeE :) I'm sorry, but I havent gotten around to testing this yet, as I'm working on a different issue right now! I'll be sure to update this post once I do, so keep it in your watchlist :)

Comment: Also beware of body { height:100% } change to height:initial

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Firstly** Bootstrap.css does come with [pre-defined print styles](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-print) such as:

```
/** 
 *  Use these for toggling content for print.
**/
.visible-print {
    display: block !important;
}

.hidden-print {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**Secondly** you can test with [page-break css rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) to separate the charts onto different pages for cleaner formatting.

```
/** 
 *  Page-break-inside seems to
 *  be required for Chrome.
**/
div.somechart { 
   page-break-after: always; 
   page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

**Third** test with formatting with the rows to take up the ***full width*** on print screen rather than relying on percentages of the `span3`/`col-*-3`'s and `span4`/`col-*-4`'s, because it would seem they are behaving *correctly* in some way when you take into account:

- Sytem printing page margins
- Bootstrap's @print defined margins
- Page gutters
- span percentages at print screen.

**Finally** the last *small* thing that's helpful to note (Yes, despite the custom `@print` style!):

```
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

to:

```
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
```

Comment: Ok, so I've tried this, and my print looks exactly the same :( No background colors or much of a structure. Just a few borders around it all. By that I mean that I added `visible-print` to a few tags and tested, like so: `<div class="container-fluid visible-print" id="report-container">`

Comment: Ah! Sorry to hear :( And that's even after changing all the `span4` & `span5`s to `span12`s? I'm supposing the charts are all using pixel widths whilst everything else is in percentages

Comment: Yeah :( Changed them all. The charts automatically stretches to their parents width, so I don't see how giving them a specific px width would change anything? Then again, I'm no designer, nor do I know css that well, so I may be wrong. Chances are that I am.. ;) I don't have any percentage widths, only the spans.

Comment: @NicklasWinger I had to do a small `.xsl` project a couple of days ago which I kinda ran into the same problem, added a couple of points that were important too :)

Comment: Thanks alot for the effort @MackieeE :) I'll look into it and let you know :)

Comment: @MackieeE is this answer still up-to-date or outdated ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! its working, (@secondly one i have used)