# IE9 - CSS failing when printing

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I'm having problems when it comes to print in EI9. It seems that the css is failing, but it works great in IE10, IE11, Firefox and Chrome.

I read about bootstrap (yes, I'm using it) and html5 issues when it comes to this browser, but I couldn't find a solution that works in my case.

This is the most significant thing that I've tried so far:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="dest/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might help.
[Printing Twitter Bootstrap correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974662/printing-twitter-bootstrap-correctly)

This site has a pretty detailed explination for html and js browser hacks. http://browserhacks.com

You could also try forcing the IE mode. Like set it to edge.
[IE Compatibility Mode: 'X-UA-Compatible' tag 'Edge'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275356/ie-compatibility-mode-x-ua-compatible-tag-edge-question)

This is a long shot.. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973479

Comment: Couldn't fix it, I had to change my plans. Thank you anyway, at least I learned something with all the links you provided.