# Page break styles not working using bootstrap3

Tags: css, printing, twitter-bootstrap-3

We have created a website using bootstrap3. While am trying to print the page mobile view is printed. I have made necessary code changes to print in desktop view.

But Page break styles are not getting applied. I have used the following code:

```
.avoid-break-inside {
  page-break-inside: avoid !important
}

.break-before{
  page-break-before: always !important
}

.break-after {
  page-break-after: always; 
}
```

Comment: refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974662/printing-twitter-bootstrap-correctly