# All Website Styling Lost when Printing

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, svg, sass

I have a website written in rails (not originally written by me). During the course of development there have been various css files used and then a scss file introduced and after most of the styling was already set, a developer installed bootstrap. Obviously this is not ideal. I am trying to get the site to look halfway decent for printing. Currently when I hit print ALL css styling is lost. SVG images lose their sizing, all fonts go to Times New Roman, white background, etc etc. Obviously some styling changes are to be expected between the screen and print media queries, but this is beyond that. I am planning on spending some time on some print media queries but I think I'm missing something. Why is ALL css being lost for print?

Comment: Is this behavior consistent across browsers? There's a couple of known issues regarding printing and suggested workarounds for them on the [bootstrap docs](https://www.rewardsciences.com/)

Comment: There's additional guidance about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302819/how-to-create-a-printable-twitter-bootstrap-page) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974662/printing-twitter-bootstrap-correctly). It's probably worth it to cast the issues listed there out in order to narrow down the problem a little bit.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and add it to the question.

Comment: Try html2Canvas which will give you screenshot of webpage and you can save or print it.